# Align CheckBox in CheckedTextView to the right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

Is there a way to align CheckBox to the right in CheckedTextView? Right now it sticks immediately after the text, but I want the checkbox to be always at the same position in the right. I know I can create a separate View ( with TextView and CheckBox ) for it and then customize, but I want to stick with CheckedTextView

Comment: its supposed to go to the right. post your xml, you probably missed something in the layout declaration, like the layout_width of the checkedtextview

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! The problem was here android:layout_width="wrap_content"